# Macbook Pro M2 Trackpad click feedback barely noticable

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, click, haptic-feedback

I've been using my Macbook Pro M2 for a few months and couldn't complain. However, since yesterday I can barely notice the haptic click feedback of the trackpad. I have not changed anything in the settings. I did however clean the Laptop with a screen cleaner (which I have done countless times before).

I compared the click feedback with my girlfriends Macbook and the difference is very noticeable (and it seems to be getting worse).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check whether a restart improves things. Also, see if changing the click strength in System Settings helps.

However, spraying liquid directly onto the trackpad is a bad idea. Make sure you spray onto a cloth, and then wipe with the cloth.

However, this is a brand new laptop, so if you're worried about the hardware, I would take it to an Apple Store, or the shop where you bought it, to see what they can find.

Comment: i have restarted recently (also installed macos sonoma), with no luck

Comment: @AnzorAsadov Reinstalling the OS is rarely a fix, or necessary. You could try a brand new user account, and see if the problem is still there. That will tell you whether it's a problem in your original user account, or at the system level.

Comment: I did not reinstall, I just updated the OS. 
However, the trackpad slowly reverted to normal over the course of the day. weird